# Who regulates ham radio satellites?

Tags: legal, satellites

I have doubts regarding the control authority of the amateur radio satellites, because recently we have drastic changes to Internet control by FCC as the next major decentralized communication system that can affect the way we communicate in future is the Amateur radio in the free world.

So, can any one country make a decision based on those satellites? I ask this because recently Israel capital decision is also headed by the US, and it is accepted by the UN. So, can it be controlled or not?

Comment: I started editing your question, but I put this on hold because it is unclear what you are asking. I am not sure how Net Neutrality on the Internet has anything to do with ham radio satellites. **Do these satellites use the Internet?** Last I knew, *they do not.*

Comment: All satellites are regulated by the ITU, an agency of the UN

Comment: @ScottEarle Thanks! I take it that satellites are controlled directly from earth-based amateur stations, and the Internet has nothing to do with this? If that's the case, feel free to reopen this, etc.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response.i know that UN controls them but can they be one-sided by the US

Comment: Your question seems to talk a lot about politics and very little about amateur radio. Removal of those parts would improve the question and reduce people's likelihood to debate your question as not everyone sees the political parts the way you do.

Comment: Ultimately, no state is bound by any international treaties except by laws of that state. Since those laws can usually be changed, there is no guarantee that what exists now will continue. However, many states find it useful to have a framework that will ease interaction with other states. Several states refuse to recognize others in the UN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_with_limited_recognition . This is more of a political question than an amateur radio question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about political authority than amateur radio.

Comment: Some comments indicate that some people think it is "political" and should be closed. At first, I would have agreed with this. However, IMHO 'Who is the regulatory body that controls, makes, and enforces the laws about Amateur Radio satellites' is a valid one. (And it may have been edited since then.) Some satellites up there were launched into orbit by countries **other than the USA**. AFAIK, *the FCC can only control what licensed amateurs in the USA do*. Also, the OP is apparently not in the USA.

Comment: @MikeWaters Certainly there could be a good question buried under the political stuff. But I don't see how the location of Israel's capital has anything to do with amateur radio.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that how the US can influence its power in UN  to make nations to vote on its side even though they don't like it and eventually I fear someday amateur radio could disrupt its motives and concentrate on this free world of communication like it did for Internet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When all the communications of a satellite qualify as amateur radio satellite communications, then the frequency coordination is carried out by [IARU](http://www.iaru.org/satellite.html). ITU delegates this function to IARU.

The link provides instructions and information for filing a coordination request.

(Background: [I filed a satellite coordination](http://www.amsatuk.me.uk/iaru/finished_detail.php?serialnum=311) in 2013, launch was in june 2014.)

Answer (score 3):

While @Juancho correctly addressed the practical frequency coordination aspects, the OP's question seems to indicate concern regarding the regulation of what is and is not communicated using the satellites.

In the USA, the permissible communications on, and the remote control of, amateur radio satellites is regulated by the FCC as defined in Part 97. A licensee wishing to use a satellite for communications should consult the jurisdictional regulatory authority for their operations.

Answer (score 0):

All satellites, commercial and amateur (and possibly even military) are regulated by the ITU, an agency of the U.N.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_law)

Comment: I don't see anything in Wikipedia to directly back up your claim. If anything, this is a gross simplification.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Wikipedia is not the last word, and *anyone* can edit that site.

Comment: @MikeWaters I'm not the one citing Wikipedia as a source.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Ahh yes. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For the United States of America:
https://www.fcc.gov/wireless/bureau-divisions/mobility-division/amateur-radio-service
 For the rest of the world, I have done little to no research but believe the overall governing body would be the International Telecommunication Union, or ITU, a body of the U.N.
Here would be the wiki site which was referred to as not being available

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Telecommunication_Union